# Crystal Report: Rounding off field automatically on using Sum formula, Visual Studio 2008

Tags: visual-studio-2008, crystal-reports-2008

Trying to sum amount field on the basis of group field.
but system is automatically rounding of the decimals. I want output with decimals.
Also, i am using formatting option to show data with 2 decimals

Ex: 500.73 is automatically changed to 501.00

Using Crystal reports with Visual Studio 2008

Answer (score 0):

Approach1:

Try as below

```
ToText(<<Databasefiled>>,2,"")
```

Approch2:

```
Right clikc of summary field  ---> Format ---> Number tab ---> select the required format
```

Comment: I am already doing Number format, hence it is showing me output data with precision as "XXX.00"
what i feel, the system is doing rounding when it is trying to sum the field on the basis of Group.

Comment: it won't do unless you specify the option.. have you tried giving the required format?

Comment: Yes. I did the same still not working.

Right Click the Field -> Format Object -> Number
but Still the same.
Out is coming with decimals as 00
Ex: sum of a group was 10.58 -> Report is showing me 11.00 (with decimal after rounding off)

Comment: I am not able to do that. 
can u please guide me. how to do that.. 
Thank in adv. or your support

Comment: What I mean to say is you have inserted summary.. now create a formula as `Display` and in that write the `Totext` code I gave above in `databasefield` place take your `summary`